# Ajax post data into Codeigniter controller but it is showing an empty array, instead of showing data into the array list

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

After submit Ajax form then posts values are not displayed codeigniter controller it return empty array instead of array values from the form

```
$("#frmDemo").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var marital_status = $('#marital_status').val();

    if (name == "" || comment == "" || marital_status == "") {
        $("#error_message").show().html("All Fields are Required");
    } else {
        $("#error_message").html("").hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/Ajax_Post_Controller/user_data_submit",
            data: "name=" + name + "&comment=" + comment + "&marital_status=" + marital_status,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#success_message').fadeOut("slow");
                }, 2000);

            }
        });
    }
})
```

Empty array output:

```
Array ( 
  [name] => admin@2016comment=somnathmarital_statusjagtap 
  [comment] => 
  [marital_status] => 
)
```

Comment: I think syntax is missing  in data:name="+name+" please let me help anybody

Comment: Don't build the query string by hand. Do `{ name: name, comment: comment, marital_status: marital_status }` instead.

Comment: Great..! works for me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `serialize()` the form if the form has all the parameters you need.

```
var form_data=$('#frmDemo').serialize();
```

And then pass the serialized form to data:

```
data:form_data
```

OR

As @Juhana mentioned, you can pass an object which would be then be turned into query string:

```
data:{ name: name, comment: comment, marital_status: marital_status }
```